# Select current table name from postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that consists of multiple subqueries that are combined by `UNION ALL`.

```sql
SELECT pan_hash, amount FROM humo_txns

UNION ALL

SELECT pan_hash, amount FROM uzcard_txns

LIMIT 10;
```

But after retrieving the data I need to somehow find out the source of the data, so I thought it would be a good idea to also include the table name, where the data came from, as a new column.

So is there any way to accomplish something like this?

```sql
SELECT <table_name>, pan_hash, amount FROM humo_txns

UNION ALL

SELECT <table_name>, pan_hash, amount FROM uzcard_txns

LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to hard-code the table names. You can use the special built-in [system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) `tableoid` which identifies the table from which a row comes from. As the `tableoid` is a number, you need to cast it to a [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) to see the actual name:

```
SELECT tableoid::regclass AS table_name, pan_hash, amount 
FROM humo_txns
UNION ALL
SELECT tableoid::regclass, pan_hash, amount 
FROM uzcard_txns
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for. I will check it out little bit later

Comment: Not working for me, using `SELECT tableoid::regclass AS table_name, ...` I'm getting `There is a column named "tableoid" in table "custom_field_sections", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply select text literals and use some column alias for this:

```
SELECT 'humo_txns' AS table_name, pan_hash, amount FROM humo_txns
UNION ALL
SELECT 'uzcard_txns' AS table_name, pan_hash, amount FROM uzcard_txns
LIMIT 10;
```

(This gives you ten arbitrarily chosen rows from all the rows in the tables, just as in your query. Thus you may get rows from both tables or rows from only one table.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT 'humo_txns', pan_hash, amount FROM humo_txns
UNION ALL
SELECT 'uzcard_txns', pan_hash, amount FROM uzcard_txns
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What do you buy by wrapping it that way?

Comment: @shawnt00, nothing :) I thought the limit would be for both the select statements

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function to do this, you have to type the name in manually in each select

```
SELECT CAST('humo_txns' AS VARCHAR(64)) AS table_name, pan_hash, amount FROM humo_txns

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST('uzcard_txns' AS VARCHAR(64)) AS table_name, pan_hash, amount FROM uzcard_txns
```

I recommend to cast at least in the first query to a varchar field which is long enough to hold any table name.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary a string constant will automatically have the type `text`. But if you do want the cast, `varchar(64)` would be enough for a table name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for this extra info, I am not that familiar with Postgres, in some RDBMS the data type is determined by sampling the data in the first query which could lead to unexpected behavior, hence the recommendation. Changing the size to 64 as you recommended.

Comment: There is indeed a function for this (as most of the time in postgres) as the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name states => tableoid::regclass
So this answers first sentence is a false claim.